# Angular - service for holding data, controller as the glue - also big data?

Tags: angularjs, memory, angularjs-controller, angular-services

I often read, that you should not hold data in the controller and use a service instead. And use the Controller more as a glue between the view and the service. 
So I really to follow this rule and it's making it a lot cleaner and easier, also when i need to access the same data from another controller. (login, settings)

But sometimes i have a really really big array of objects (customers, items) which i load now in the controller and not in the service. Because i think all this data would fill up the memory, since services are singletons. But it also feels wrong to load everytime the same data again. so which way should i go now?

Best Regards

Comment: I don't understand your question: why would the data "fill up" the memory in a service but not in a controller?

Comment: cause if i leave the view with the customerController it will free up the memory until i load the controller again.. or am i wrong :S

Comment: Have you tested this or still basing it on `"I think"`? We can't check it...we don't even know what `big` means